# Converting Varchar to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having two fields holding data as varchar

> field1= 10,000.00 and field2= 5,000.00

I now need to add these two fields to find sum . But when I add as Field1+Field2 the

> result is 10,000.005,000.oo

I tried to  use CAST(Field1 as decimal(12,2)) but it throws a error that it cannot convert varchar to numeric.

Help me out.!

```
                        SELECT     [1] AS ContractPriceExcluded, [2] AS Anticipated, [3] AS Approved, [4] AS claims, [5] AS ProvisionalSums, [6] AS CommitmentsToDate, [7] AS AnticipatedFCost, 
                  [8] AS VarianceToContract, [9] AS CertifiedPayments,[10] AS ContractPriceIncluded , [11] AS ProvisionalSumsNotactivated ,description, status, ReferenceNo
                    FROM         (SELECT     ISNULL([Workflow_CustomFormfields].[fieldnumber], '') AS fieldnumber, 
                                         CAST( REPLACE([Workflow_CustomFormFields].fieldvalue,',','')as Decimal(12,2))  AS fieldvalue, isnull(workflow_customforms.subject, '') AS description, 
                                          isnull(workflow_customforms.categoryvalue, '') AS status, isnull(workflow_customforms.reference, '') AS ReferenceNo
                   FROM          [dbo].[Workflow_CustomFormfields] INNER JOIN
                                          dbo.Workflow_CustomForms ON [dbo].[Workflow_CustomForms].[Id] = dbo.Workflow_CustomFormfields.customformId
                   WHERE      dbo.Workflow_CustomForms.ProjectId = 1 AND dbo.Workflow_CustomForms.CustomformtypeId = 75) PS PIVOT (max(fieldvalue) FOR fieldnumber IN ([1], [2], 
                  [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9],[10],[11])) AS pivot_fieldvalue
```

Comment: Why don't you store it as decimal in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

```
 select cast(replace('10,000.00',',','') as decimal(12,2))
```

The problem is in comma

Comment: Hi this solution works fine. But when I use this inside the case statement it throws me the same error.Check below for the case statement i used.

Comment: (CASE WHEN [workflow_customformfields].FieldType = 'Date' THEN dbo.CustomForm_GetDate(workflow_customformfields.fieldvalue) 
             WHEN  [workflow_customformfields].FieldType = 'Double' THEN 
            CAST(REPLACE(Workflow_CustomFormFields.fieldvalue,',','') as Decimal(12,2))
             
                                              ELSE isnull(workflow_customformfields.fieldvalue, '') END) AS fieldvalue

Comment: while running the above code it throws me the same error i faced. Cannot convert varchar to numeric.

Comment: You are trying to put 3 different types in one column. CustomForm_GetDate() - I think returns `Date`, CAST(REPLACE(Workflow_CustomFormFields.fieldvalue,',','') as Decimal(12,2)) - returns `Decimal` and isnull(workflow_customformfields.fieldvalue, '') will return `varchar`

Comment: Check my full code in the question above (Edited)below . I even removed the case statement but the error is still pertaining. @MikkaRin

Answer (score 0):

Are you casting both values as decimal? This works fine

```
DECLARE @one varchar(8), @two varchar(8)
SET @one = '10,000.00'
SET @two = '5,000.00'
SELECT CAST(replace(@one,',','') AS decimal(12,2))+
       CAST(replace(@two,',','') AS decimal(12,2))
```

Comment: please have a look to question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the comma and convert to decimal. See below.

```
declare @field1 varchar(50) = '10,000.00' ,
 @field2 varchar(50)= '5,000.00'

select Convert(decimal(10,2),replace(@field1,',','')) +Convert(decimal(10,2),replace(@field2,',',''))
```